# Campo secundario autoincremental en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

buen día!

Hago este thread porque estoy trabajando con una base de datos de transformadores

El tema es el siguiente, yo tengo algo así..

**Tabla Transformador**

```
*Código comercial
1º Cliente
1º Nota de venta
Fecha de diseño
Norma
```

etcetera

El asunto, es que pueden existir dos transformadores iguales, exactamente iguales, pero cambien en los datos garantizados..
Cuando hice la normalización llegué a esta segunda tabla..

**Tabla Dato Garantizado**

```
*Codigo comercial
*Version
Aplicación primaria
Aplicación secundaria
```

etcetera.

El problema es el siguiente, para implementar esta estructura, tendría que tener en la tabla **Dato Garantizado** una clave compuesta, donde una (en este caso Versión) sea autoincremental, cosa que por lo que leí no es una buena práctica.
Y claro está un Código comercial para identificar a que transformador corresponden esos datos garantizados.

No hace mucho que he empezado a trabajar en lo que es bases de datos, por lo que es posible que sea un error muy simple, pero no se me ocurre como modificar la estructura de modo que pueda esquivar la clave primaria compuesta autoincremental

Desde ya muchísimas gracias por leer mi pregunta!

Comment: Si mal no entendí, lo que necesitas es que por cada Transformador, tengas un versionado propio? Algo como `código=transformador1, version=1`, `código=transformador1, version=2`, `código=transformador2, version=1`, etc.?

Comment: Codigo comercial es tu Id? Supongo que tienes una tabla de cliente y otra para nota de venta. Despues se relacionan en `Transformador.`

Comment: @quinqui Exacto!

Comment: @Angel Sí, codigo_comercial es mi id, los campos nota de venta, cliente, etc, son texto, se toman como una característica del transformador, dice 1º porque sólo me interesa a la primera persona a la que se lo vendí

Comment: No me queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer. Creo que necesitas una tabla de versiones. Donde su id sea autoincremental. Despues tienes que hacer una tercera tabla para crear una relación mucho a muchos.

Comment: Bueno, la verdad, no sé si se puede crear una PK compuesta con una de sus columnas autoincrementales... Pero a primeras, y ya que creo que no se puede, te tocaría hacer el incremento de manera manual :o Intentaré investigar si es posible, porque tiene lógica el que se permitiera.

Comment: @Angel Exactamente, esa fue la solución, no se como no lo noté :P Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @quinqui posible es, haciendo que cada vez que se agrega un registro hace una subquery buscando cual es el último id y añade uno nuevo, pero es una solución que el día de mañana se padecería :P

Comment: Es cuestion de ir practicando. :D